# Passing around information via JSF FacesContexts

Tags: jsf, attributes, facescontext

I have a listener that listens for JSF validation failures, and I need to be able to turn off a specific piece of functionality depending on certain contexts.

In my listener I only have the SystemEvent, so this listener isn't component specific, I was wondering if there was any way to pass around any other information, perhaps something like attributes on the FacesContext?...so that later in the validation listener I could check the context for an attribute that I could set in the JSF.

Ie

```
<f:someContextParam name="turnOff" value="true"/>
```

then later

```
boolean turnOff = (Boolean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().someWayToGetAttribute("turnOff");
```

...seems like a shot in the dark, I'm just trying to see if theres any contextual way to pass back information before I rewrite the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose a `<f:attribute>` tag inside your input component and then retrieve the attribute value inside the validator via    `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(attrname);`

Syntax for the tag should be `<f:attribute name="attrname" value="#{ELexpr}">`

Here's a semi complete example validator:

```
public class NameValidator implements Validator 
{
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException
    {
        Object value = (String)component.getAttributes().get("FIELD_NAME");
        // validate stuff
    }
}
```

and corresponding jsf

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{registrationManager.name}">
    <f:validator validatorId="nameValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="FIELD_NAME" value="#{registrationManager.numAttempts}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

**Updated**
Fixed the wrong use of the context to get the attribute to get it from the component instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I should have been clearer, I'm not actually within a custom validator; I'm in a listener that is listening for validation fails. Essentially what I was looking for was something similar to your solution but adding the attribute to the context instead of to a specific component/validator. Also, if you add an attribute to a validator, you should actually have to retreive it from the component; ie (String) component.getAttributes().get("FIELD_NAME")

Comment: Ugh, thanks for catching that. I'll update the answer to at least reflect correct code, even though it might not work for your specific needs.